# How do you change the positioning of the modal button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I can't figure this out. I'm using the Bootstrap modal for my website and I want to change the positioning of the button, not the dialogue box. No matter what I change, it's stuck to the left of the page. This is what I have in index

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Event</button>
```

How would I move this around the page?

Comment: Use `#myModal` as a selector in your CSS file and then apply a `position` to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you be to use the top,bottom,left, and right css properties. Here is some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) explaining them. Here is a  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gV6y8/84/ I edited that moves modal button around. Hope it helps.

Here is the code inside of the fiddle:

html:

```
    <a id="modalbutton" data-toggle="modal" href="#defaultModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Default Modal</a>
    <br>

    <div id="defaultModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                    <h4 id="modal-label">Example Without Pull Right Modal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div> <!--modal-content-->
        </div> <!--modal-dialog-->
    </div> <!--modal-->
```

css:

```
    #modalbutton{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:100px;
        left: 400px;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! This fixed the positioning issue, but now when I click on the button, nothing will open, it's stuck on the hover color. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there anyway you could possible provide me with a jsfiddle containing your code?

Comment: Hey @Rosalee sorry to get back to you so late. It seems you have linked me the same jsfiddle as I sent you. Once you update the information in the jsfiddle click the update button and it should provide you with a new fiddle. If you could link me the new one I will defiantly look at it for you.

Comment: Also if you don't mind if my solution solved your original question could you please click the green check mark next my answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you look in the css, you can see the following class:

```
.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  opacity: .2;
}
```

I would create another stylesheet that loads after this in your document, and add another `.close` class and add `float:left;`